# python, mongoengine ReferenceField duplicate key error

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

So I have these models:

```
class Podcast(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    category_id = ReferenceField(Category)
```

and:

```
class Category(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True, unique=True)
```

When I try to insert a new podcast that has a category that another podcast already has, I get this error:

```
mongoengine.errors.NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error collection:myapp.podcast index: category_id.name_1 dup key: { : null })
```

How I am inserting a podcast:

```
category = 'Comedy'

if not CategoryFacade.categoryExists(category):
    cat = CategoryFacade.createCategory(category)
else:
    cat = CategoryFacade.get(category)

podcast = {
    'name': pod['name'] if 'name' in pod else None,
    'category_id': cat.to_dbref()
}

PodcastFacade.createPodcast(podcast)
```

the createPodcast method in PodcastFacade:

```
@staticmethod
def createPodcast(kwargs):
    c = Podcast(**kwargs)
    c.save()

    return c
```

The categoryExists method:

```
@staticmethod
def categoryExists(name):
    try:
        return Category.objects.get(name=name) is not None
    except DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

Comment: did you check with a debugger for the ID of the category and the result of `CategoryFacade.categoryExists(category)` during the second call?

Comment: @ezdazuzena
This is the code for that:

`
@staticmethod
    def categoryExists(name):
        try:
            return Category.objects.get(name=name) is not None
        except DoesNotExist:
            return False
`

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson did you ever manage to solve this? I'm running into the same issue